# Wired connection problem Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, networking, wired

I am not new to ubuntu, but have encountered this problem several times. I am running with a wired connection on ubuntu 12.04 LTS. When I worked with ubuntu for the first two- three weeks or so, the connection seemed to work fine, and I hadn't even set up the connection- it had been auto-detected by ubuntu, which is natural. But now, the connection seems to have not working (its not detecting at all) . On repeatedly restarting my computer, I found that the internet seeme to connect (or detect), like 1 out of 5-8 restarts. Is there any solution to this unusual problem, as I have tried all the solutions on this site and other sites too, but have not found a working solution. On my other partition on windows vista, this problem never occurs and the internet connection alway connects.
PS: If there is any extra info I have to provide like error logs or any other info just tell me and I will do so, as I desperately want a solution.

Output for sudo lshw -c network-

```
*-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: NM10/ICH7 Family LAN Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 8
   bus info: pci@0000:01:08.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 01
   serial: 00:1a:92:6b:2e:b1
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e100 driverversion=3.5.24-k2-NAPI duplex=full firmware=N/A ip=10.0.0.2 latency=32 link=yes maxlatency=56 mingnt=8 multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:20 memory:fdefe000-fdefefff ioport:ee00(size=64)
```

Output for cat /var/log/dmesg | grep eth0 -

```
[    1.199914] e100 0000:01:08.0: eth0: addr 0xfdefe000, irq 20, MAC addr    00:1a:92:6b:2e:b1
[   18.108866] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   19.317182] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   19.317593] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   19.320152] e100 0000:01:08.0: eth0: NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex
[   19.320401] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the output of `sudo lshw -c network`. Thank you. Please also add to your question the output of `cat /var/log/dmesg | grep eth0`

Comment: @ElderGeek I have changed the question, does anything here give a lead?

Comment: THe second output has the "eth0" text in red, if that's important....

Comment: It appears that the link is up. How are you determining that you are not connected to the internet?

Answer (score -1):

this is because your network configuration file sets for the default settings.

such as eth0 settings i think they are in the manual mode.

please check you interfaces settings and DNS settings

```
sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

change the eth0 from manual/static to DHCP

before editing the interface conf file, i suggest you read more about it plus DNS conf file too

Comment: This is the content of the interface file, what am I expected to change- auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

Comment: @RishitBansal the file appears to be set to defaults. I don't think changing it will help.

Comment: @ElderGeek if ip is configured in /etc/network/interfaces it won't be managed by network manager and GUI might incorrectly indicate disconnected

Comment: @meccooll are you trying to ping Ahmed?